# How can I allow a page to scroll while still capturing a dojox swipe gesture?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using [dojox/gesture/swipe](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/gesture.html#dojox-gesture-swipe) to trigger a carousel card change whenever a user performs a swipe gesture on my carousel widget.  However, it seems that the user input is effectively "trapped" within whatever element is capturing the gesture which means that the user can't scroll the page by swiping up up or down on the screen if the scrolling starts by the user tapping and swiping from within the carousel.

It seems that this is almost the intended behaviour as well since this happens even with the most bare custom gesture that simply inherits from [dojox/gesture/swipe](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/gesture.html#dojox-gesture-base) without overriding any methods.  Is there any way to let the scrolling of the page happen even while the gesture is being "interpreted" or am I misunderstanding the usage of the gesture system?  I guess the intended use may actually be a means of more robust user like interpreting letter gestures akin to a Palm Pilot.

Comment: I want to know this answer too.